# json_encode() creating object from an array with standard numeric indexing

Tags: php, json

I have an issue with `json_encode()` whereby it is taking a standard numeric PHP array and encoding it as a JSON object instead of a JSON array, which is making the JSON string huge, when it doesn't need to be.

I'm certain the PHP array being encoded has standard numeric indexing, because I'm passing it through `array_values()`. Any idea why `json_encode()` is behaving this way?

```
$array = array_values([1,2,3,4]);
$json = json_encode($array);
// $json = { "0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4 } .... why?
```

Thank you

Comment: [Testing this](https://www.tehplayground.com/VkQmNQt0ZQ4ZE7uo) (7.2, 7.1, 7.0, and 5.6), I only got an object out of it when I created an associative array with numerical keys, which is not what you did. What version of PHP are you on? Can you share your `json_*` config values from `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Does _anything_ else happen to `$json` before you output it? Are you printing it directly or is it output through some kind of controller method?

Comment: Not reproducible https://3v4l.org/lFfTX

Comment: @zbee JSON doesn't appear to have any configuration options. https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.configuration.php

Comment: Thanks @Don'tPanic, there was something hidden, preceding the encode function that was merging arrays and adding a non-default numeric index. Waste of a question - sorry guys.

Comment: It's okay! Often the answer really is just getting yourself to look for the solution in a place you weren't expecting to find it. When I am stuck looking at something that just isn't making sense I find it sometimes helps to step away from the problem for a little while. Just some unsolicited advice from someone who ends up in that situation far too often. ;-)